# how to download document using download url in liferay?

Tags: java, liferay, autologin

I have developed a web service using service builder portlet, which will return a list of documents from Liferay (6.2 EE). I am returning the default document download URL like the following:

```
{
    ...
    "downloadUrl": "http://localhost:8080/documents/10181/12306/folder1_doc1/98188996-af04-41c8-b0b6-10b83bf17ee4"
}
```

When the client calls the web-service he is passing user name and password in header with basic authentication.

But when the client is trying to call the document URL with the same basic authentication Liferay returns a HTML page asking for login to access this document. How can I access the document without that login page?

Comment: Did you add BasicAuth for the second call as well? And have you used the same Login-ID as configured for your portal instance?

Comment: I have tried  BasicAuth directly for download URL(Second call) but its not working. Could you please help me get out from this problem?

Comment: Did you configure the `BasicAuthHeaderAutoLogin` correctly?

Comment: No, I am using existing inbuilt provided by Liferay.

Comment: What happens if you call http://localhost:8080/documents/10181/12306/folder1_doc1/98188996-af04-41c8-b0b6-10b83bf17ee4 in your browser?

Comment: Its directly redirecting to Liferay login page and asking for user login.

Comment: @Tobias Liefke Could you please help me to get our from this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add the `BasicAuthHeaderAutoLogin` to the `auto.login.hooks` property for your portal.

For example add this to your `portal-ext.properties`:

```
auto.login.hooks=...copy line from WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar/portal.properties...,\
    com.liferay.portal.security.auth.BasicAuthHeaderAutoLogin
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will check it and let you know.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working as per your suggestion.

Comment: I was struggling with this one, because setting on auto.login.hooks was not working for me. I found that there is a boolean property that enable/disable what is provided in auto.login.hooks.
###### The auto login filter processes the classes in the property "auto.login.hooks" to provide auto login functionality. ######
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter=true

Comment: But `AutoLoginFilter` _is_ `true` by default, so you must have turned it off on purpose?