# Liferay document download in android

Tags: android, rest, authentication, mobile, liferay

I have created http Url to download document using this way

http://localhost:8080/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=b206a058-01c7-43ef-9329-e9cf39a449cc&groupId=11107

Which reqires basic authentication.

I have added this property in portal-ext.properties for basic authentication(As suggested here -  [how to download document using download url in liferay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522468/how-to-download-document-using-download-url-in-liferay)) 
auto.login.hooks=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.BasicAuthHeaderAutoLogin

It works fine in rest client when I pass basic authentication.

But when the same Url is hit by android app (passing Url to android download manager with basic authentication in authentication header), it downloads bin file and when I click on that file it redirects me to login page of liferay.

My android code is like this:

```
    String str = "email:password";
    String enco = Base64.encodeToString(str.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    downloadManager.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadUrl))
                                    .addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + enco)
    .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED));
```

Is there any other way to download document of Liferay in mobile devices?

Comment: Please try renamig the downloaded file by replacing extension to original, and see if it opens

Comment: Just to be sure and rule out the obvious: You don't use "localhost" in the URL when accessing from Android, right?

Comment: Yes, In original app I am using actual IP instead of localhost.